# Show one day, one hour ago not working correctly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, relative-time-span

i have done with this code

```
+ (NSString *)relativeDateStringForDate:(NSString *)date
{
    NSString *temp;

    NSString* format = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";
    // Set up an NSDateFormatter for UTC time zone
    NSDateFormatter* formatterUtc = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatterUtc setDateFormat:format];
    [formatterUtc setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    // Cast the input string to NSDate
    NSDate* utcDate = [formatterUtc dateFromString:date];
    // Set up an NSDateFormatter for the device's local time zone
    NSDateFormatter* formatterLocal = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatterLocal setDateFormat:format];
    [formatterLocal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    // Create local NSDate with time zone difference
    NSDate* localDate = [formatterUtc dateFromString:[formatterLocal stringFromDate:utcDate]];
    //calender settings
    NSCalendarUnit units = NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit |
    NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond ;
    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    //local dates
    NSDate* datetime = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatterUtc setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:format];
    NSString* dateTimeInIsoFormatForZuluTimeZone = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:datetime];
    NSDate* sysUTCDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateTimeInIsoFormatForZuluTimeZone];


    NSDateFormatter* formatterLocalFromUtc = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatterLocalFromUtc setDateFormat:format];
    [formatterLocalFromUtc setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    // Create local NSDate with time zone difference
    NSDate* curreentDate = [formatterUtc dateFromString:[formatterLocalFromUtc stringFromDate:sysUTCDate]];

    NSDateComponents *components1 = [cal components:(NSCalendarUnitEra|NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay |NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond) fromDate:curreentDate];
    NSDate *today = [cal dateFromComponents:components1];

    //server date
    components1 = [cal components:(NSCalendarUnitEra|NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond) fromDate:localDate];
    NSDate *thatdate = [cal dateFromComponents:components1];



    // if `date` is before "now" (i.e. in the past) then the components will be positive
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:units
                                                                   fromDate:thatdate
                                                                     toDate:today
                                                                    options:0];



    if (components.year > 0) {
        temp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld years ago", (long)components.year];
    } else if (components.month > 0) {
        temp= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld months ago", (long)components.month];
    } else if (components.weekOfYear > 0) {
        temp= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld weeks ago", (long)components.weekOfYear];
    } else if (components.day > 0) {
        if (components.day > 1) {
            temp= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld day ago", (long)components.day];
        } else {
            temp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld day ago", (long)components.day];
        }
    } else {
        if (components.hour!=0) {
            if(components.hour==1)
            {
                temp= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld hour ago",(long)components.hour];
            }
            else
            {
                temp= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld hours ago",(long)components.hour];
            }

        } else if (components.minute!=0){
            if(components.minute==1)
            {
                temp= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld min ago",(long)components.minute];
            }
            else
            {
                temp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld mins ago",(long)components.minute];
            }

        }
        else if (components.second!=0){
            if(components.second==1)
            {
                temp= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld sec ago",(long)components.second];
            }
            else
            {
                temp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld secs ago",(long)components.second];
            }

        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

But its not showing correctly.If i post any record to server,its shows **-1 secs ago**
How to solve this with above code.

My server date response is **NSString**

**2015-09-16T14:16:49.187Z**

I need to calculate curent time with server date diffrence.

To avoid this i have added +2 secs manaually

```
temp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld secs ago",(long)components.second+2];
```

thats not good way to get this done, please help me with this.

Comment: this is the wrong way **To avoid this i have added +2 secs manaually** dont do this what the result u get here  **NSDate* utcDate** and **NSDate* localDate**

Comment: utcDate is srver date and i set date formatter to change local timezone and store it in locaDate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Create Time Ago thing i used [NSDate-TimeAgo](https://github.com/kevinlawler/NSDate-TimeAgo) and `#import "NSDate+TimeAgo.h"` in app delegate i create + method like following:

```
+(NSString*)GetTimeAgofromDate:(NSString*)DateString
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    // voila!
    dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:DateString];
    NSTimeInterval timeZoneSeconds = [[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT];
    NSDate *dateInLocalTimezone = [dateFromString dateByAddingTimeInterval:timeZoneSeconds];


    NSDateFormatter *workingHoursFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [workingHoursFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
   // NSString *str = [workingHoursFormatter stringFromDate:dateInLocalTimezone];
    //;
    NSString *timeAgoFormattedDate = [dateInLocalTimezone timeAgo];


    return timeAgoFormattedDate;

}
```

Might be this is helpful to you.

Comment: this is my working code and that work parfect at my end please make sure the date format